# Solr comparison functions report "Unknown function"

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm attempting to write a reasonably basic boost function for Solr 4.x server.

I wish for my boost function to work as such (pseudocode)

```
if (weight >= 700) boost = 1.5
```

The boost function I'm passing to Solr is the following

```
if(gte(weight,700),1.5,1)
```

I receive the following error message when submitting the query though the Solr admin UI.

> "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unknown function gte in FunctionQuery('if(gte(weight,700),1.5,1)', pos=7)"

I've tried the other basic comparison functions I've found in the documentation (`gt`, `lt`, `lte`). but encountered the same issue.

Are these functions available in Solr 4.x? The documentation I've found hasn't been specific which version they were introduced in. Is there any functions available in Solr 4.x which would perform the desired comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you mention was [added in 6.2.0](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_2_0/changes/Changes.html#v6.2.0.new_features).

You can rewrite the query to something like `if(max(0, sub(weight, 700)), 1.5, 1.0)` - if the value is less than 700, use 0 - the if test will fail and give 1.0. Otherwise it'll use the actual value, and will be evaluated as true, and give 1.5. If you want `gte`, subsitute `700` with `699` or whatever your smallest step size is. Example and step wise computation:

```
weight = 800

sub(weight, 700) => 100
max(0, 100) => 100
if (100) => 1.5
```

Or if you have a weight below 700:

```
weight = 698

sub(weight, 698) => -2
max(0, -2) => 0
if (0) => 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. There is a missing closing bracket for the max() function which I needed to add in.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the missing parenthesis!